# Convert Spinner String values "20-34" as integer from 20 to 34 in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.1

How can i convert a Spinner String values such as "20-34",35-44"etc into integer from 20 to 34, integer from 35 to 44 in android.Below is the code for taking integer values from spinner and assigning points in order to a mathematics calculations

```
 public static int age_value(String gender, String ag) {

    int b;
    b = Integer.parseInt(ag);
    if (gender.equals("f")) {
        if (20 <= b && b <= 34) {
            ageValue = -7;
        } else if (35 <= b && b <= 39) {
            ageValue = -3;
        } else if (40 <= b && b <= 44)
            ageValue = 0;
        else if (45 <= b && b <= 49)
            ageValue = 3;
        else if (50 <= b && b <= 54)
            ageValue = 6;
        else if (55 <= b && b < 59)
            ageValue = 8;
        else if (60 <= b && b <= 64)
            ageValue = 10;
        else if (65 <= b && b <= 69)
            ageValue = 12;
        else if (70 <= b && b <= 74)
            ageValue = 14;
        else if (75 <= b && b <= 79)
            ageValue = 16;

    } else if (gender.equals("m")) {
        if (20 <= b && b <= 34) {
            ageValue = -9;
        } else if (35 <= b && b <= 39) {
            ageValue = -4;
        } else if (40 <= b && b <= 44)
            ageValue = 0;
        else if (45 <= b && b <= 49)
            ageValue = 3;
        else if (50 <= b && b <= 54)
            ageValue = 6;
        else if (55 <= b && b < 59)
            ageValue = 8;
        else if (60 <= b && b <= 64)
            ageValue = 10;
        else if (65 <= b && b <= 69)
            ageValue = 11;
        else if (70 <= b && b <= 74)
            ageValue = 12;
        else if (75 <= b && b <= 79)
            ageValue = 13;

    }


    return ageValue;


}
```

Below shows the spinner to which the above method is added

```
  int array1 = R.array.gender;
    // final String[] gender1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gender);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getApplicationContext(), array1, R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinnerdrop);
    Gender.setAdapter(adapter);
    Gender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            rowgender = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            if(rowage!=null && rowgender!=null) {
                MainActivity.age_value(rowgender, rowage);
            }

            Gender.setSelection(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

    });
```

but it shows an error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "20–34"

Comment: `-` is not an `int` , use split then parse it or  your logic can be simplified using the position of spinner's selected value like  `if(position==0)  ageValue = -7;`

Comment: What do you want A list of numbers between 20-34 or just 2 numbers 20 and 34?

Comment: `–` is not an integer .

Comment: @TheLostMind- a list of numbers from 20 to 34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String `split()` method to do that

```
String ag = "20-34";
String[] value = ag.split("-");

int b= Integer.parseInt(value[0]);// here value 20
int c= Integer.parseInt(value[1]);// here value 34
```

Then do your operations

```
    if (20 <= b && c <= 34) {
        ageValue = -7;
    } else if
     .... 
     ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8's `IntStream.range` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "20-34";
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    if (s.matches("\\d+-\\d+")) { // Check if input String is in correct format
        String[] arr = s.split("-"); // split based on "-"                 
        start = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]); // get start range
        end = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]); // get end range
    }

    List<Integer> nums = IntStream.range(start, end).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()); // use IntStream.range method to generate range.
    System.out.println(nums);
}
```

O/P :

```
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
```

There are many ways of doing this.

You can also do :

```
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(start, end).forEach(nums::add);
    System.out.println(nums);
```